# Proving iterated sum of a double series is equal to the unordered sum

Tags: real-analysis

The question below comes from Bartle, Introduction to Real Analysis section 9.1.

Let $a:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ and write $a_{ij}:=a(i,j)$. If $A_i=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$ for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and if $A:=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$, we say $A$ is an iterated sum of $a_{ij}$ and write $A=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$.

Suppose $0\leq a_{ij} \forall i,j \in \mathbb{N}$. If  $(c_k)$ is any enumeration of $\{a_{ij}:i,j\in\mathbb{N}\}$, show that the following statement are equivalent.

(i) The iterated sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$ converge to B.

(ii) The series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_k$ converge to C.

In this case, we have B=C

The above question comes from the section about absolute convergence of series ,the grouping and rearrangement of series.
I try to solve the question by rearrange and grouping the terms of $\sum c_k$
But it turns out that the infinite case is more complicated.

I am new to analysis. Can anyone gives me some hint? Thank you.

Comment: @5xum He has defined it in Line 4.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: suppose i) holds. Verify that for any $m$ we have $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} c_k \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{ij}$. [For this verify that each of the $c_k$'s appear on the right side].  This will prove that the sum in ii) does not exceed B. The proof of ii) implies i) is similar.